# Passing connection from method to other method in Python using subprocess and rpyc

Tags: python, oop

Trying to create a library, which does this-Connect to Unix box, pass this connection to next method and run a shell script. Also i am calling this methods in other file.
New to python, please help.

**file1:**

```
from file2 import *
def start():
        one=libs()
        one.connect()
        one.run()
```

**file2:**

```
import rpyc

class libs():
    def connect(self):
        self.conn=rpyc.classic.connect("hostname")
        self.remote=self.conn.modules.subprocess
        return
    def run(self):

        p1="sh -vx /tmp/test.sh"
        self.result=self.remote.Popen(p1,shell=True,stdout=remote.PIPE,stderr=remote.PIPE)
        out,err=self.result.communicate()
        print out,err
        return out,err
```

What wrong am i doing, I m trying to implement OOPS here.Getting no error or output just code exits with 0
have tried this also combining both methods in file2 into one,and then calling one method only in file1.

```
import rpyc

class libs():
p1="sh -vx /tmp/test.sh"
    def connect(self,p1):
        self.conn=rpyc.classic.connect("hostname")
        self.remote=self.conn.modules.subprocess


self.result=self.remote.Popen(p1,shell=True,stdout=remote.PIPE,stderr=remote.PIPE)
        out,err=self.result.communicate()
        print out,err
        return out,err
```

Comment: Did you try it directly from one single function? Did it word there and what it the current error or problem? Currently, this question is rather broad...

Comment: No error no output code exits with 0.`code`def connect(self):
        self.conn=rpyc.classic.connect("hostname")
        self.remote=self.conn.modules.subprocess p1="sh -vx /tmp/test.sh"
        self.result=self.remote.Popen(p1,shell=True,stdout=remote.PIPE,stderr=remote.PIPE)
        out,err=self.result.communicate()
        print out,err
        return out,err `code` And then calling only one method in file1

Comment: What is in `/tmp/test.sh` on the remote system?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start learning python first ?

When you call a function or a method or whatever is callable you need parenthesis...

```
def start():
        one=libs()
        one.connect()
        one.run()
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out it was a typo while asking question,corrected it.